# Spring boot Web Client to handle retries along with success and error response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webclient

I am trying to create Spring boot web client to handle success and error responses along with retries. I am able to handle success/error responses with out retires. Below is the code I created to handle response dynamically.

```
protected <R,T> Mono<T> Post(final String endpoint, 
                             final MultiValuesMap<String,String) headers,
                             final R requestBody,
                             final Class<? extends T> responseType,
                             final Class<? extends T> errorResponseType) {
       return webclient.post().uri(endpoint).
              headers(httpHeaders.addAll(headers).bodyValue(requestBody).
              exhangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                  if(clientResponse.statusCode.isError()){
                     return clientResponse.bodyToMono(errorResponseType);
                  }
                   return clientResponse.bodyToMono(responseType);
              });}
```

The above generic code is expecting as expected if use like below will able to handle both success and Error Responses

```
BaseResponse response = post("url",headers,requestBoy,SuccessResponse.class,ErrorResponse.class).
 //SuccessResponse,ErrorResponse extends some BaseResponse class
```

Now I am trying to add extra Retry logic to above like below,

```
protected <R,T> Mono<T> Post(final String endpoint, 
                                 final MultiValuesMap<String,String) headers,
                                 final R requestBody,
                                 final Class<? extends T> responseType,
                                 final Class<? extends T> errorResponseType) {
           return webclient.post().uri(endpoint).
                  headers(httpHeaders.addAll(headers).bodyValue(requestBody).
                  exhangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                      if(clientResponse.statusCode.isError()){
                         return clientResponse.bodyToMono(errorResponseType);
                      }
                       return clientResponse.bodyToMono(responseType);
                  }).retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(3,Duration.ofMillis(100L)).
                     doAfterRetry(retrySignal -> log.info(retrySignal.totalRetries()).
                     filter(this::is5xxError()) 
                    //is5xxError has logic when to trigger
```

With above change I am unable achieve the same like returning BaseResponse for success and error scenarios and retries not working as expected.

Can please help on the same.